# How to retrieve multiple files in html link with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I split up my website using code refactoring with templates.

When I go to construct a basic link in my nav.php file or I suppose anywhere on the site for that mater, I need to grab multiple files as the site is templated -- let's assume for this example the user is going to services.php.

I believe I would need to attach all of these files in the link:

- header.php
- nav.php
- pages/services.php
- footer.php

How do I go about constructing a link to accomplish this? Could I make some sort of array and attach all of the files in the link and then loop through the array with a `foreach` statement and `echo` the results?

Comment: You are working way too hard here. Have you considered a content management system like Drupal? You obviously need to read about the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) at least.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm starting with an HTML template and building my own framework so to speak, but I've never actually used MVC before.

Comment: Please take a look at it. Also, check out http://codeigniter.com/. No reason to reinvent the wheel, as well as a community of support.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I've heard of this as well as CakePHP. Thank you. I actually didn't realize this is one of the reasons why people migrate to one of these frameworks. I appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't grab the other files through the link. You link to one URL, which processes a single PHP file and that PHP file includes all of the other necessary files. For example, your link might be:

```
<a href="/services.php">Services</a>
```

Which will run services.php, which will then include the header, nav, footer, etc. For example services.php could look like this:

```
require "header.php";

// Some PHP code specific to servicer.php goes here.

require "nav.php";

// Some more PHP code specific to servicer.php goes here.

require "footer.php";
```

Using something like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) would be a nice and clean way of implemtning views in a MVC setup.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. I don't know why I was having a mental lapse and couldn't think of this. Would CakePHP also be a good solution for an MVC?

Comment: @Matt - [Sure, CakePHP supports MVC](http://book.cakephp.org/view/890/Understanding-Model-View-Controller).